# Uniform column width depending on number of elements

Tags: css

Is it possible to make an arbitrary number of columns all have the same width in a flexible width container with pure CSS?

Example:

```
<div>
  <div>COL-1</div>
  ...
  <div>COL-N</div>
</div>
```

The outer div has a flexible width, the number of columns varies. The column width should be the same, regardless of the columns content width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `display:table` for outer div and `display:table-cell` for inner div

```
<div id="outer">
  <div>COL-1</div>
  <div>COL-N</div>
  <div>cvcvffff</div>
</div>
```

---

```
#outer{
    display:table;    
    width:720px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#outer>div{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black; 

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3CEvX/1/)

Comment: But the width will not be enforced in this case. If the content of one column is larger, the column width will expand (updated the question, didn't mention that requirement before).

Comment: table-layout: fixed; may fix that problem check the updated vode

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible to do so.
If you are using PHP in your code, do the following to generate the following < div > elements

```
<html>
    <style>
        div{
            width:100px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
            echo "<div>COL-$i</div>";
        ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```